# Magento 2: Print arabic invoice pdf character problem

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

I have a problem with Arabic font, when I get short_description in invoice pdf the breakpoint of the letters is not correct.[image]
Text before transfer to pdf invoice
All Purpose Flour AL BAKER

آرد همه منظوره ال بیکر

طحین لجمیع الاستعمالات البیکر

AL BAKER Un
**And after pdf print**
All Purpose Flour AL BAKER
نیحط رکیب لا هروظنم همه درآ
AL رکیبلا تالامعتسالا عیمجل
BAKER Un